# How to remove space, underscore from this regexp [^\w \xC0-\xFF]

Tags: php, javascript, regex

How to detect space, underscore is invalid? It has to be one word. But not working with

`[^\w \xC0-\xFF]`

- if i do \w\xC0-\xFF i can detect the space
- but how do i detect the 'underscore' ?

Inputs are invalid: `username1234 _1234` or `username 1234`

Comment: @Umbrella: I think what he is trying to say is that the regular expression should successfully match if the input is *invalid*. This is why it needs to only match one character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the space is easy as you already pointed out:

```
[^\w\xC0-\xFF]
```

Removing the underscore requires knowing that `\w` is the same as `[0-9A-Za-z_]`. So to also remove the underscore you can use this:

```
[^0-9A-Za-z\xC0-\xFF]
```